# Proving convergence by the ratio test.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I try to prove by the ratio test that this serie converge :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n+1)^n}{n^{2n}}$$

I know I have to demonstrate that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|$$

But, I cannot seem to be able to simplify the following expression,
$$\left| \frac{(2(n+1)+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{2(n+1)}} \cdot \frac{n^{2n}}{(2n+1)^n} \right| $$

Can you give me a hint!?

Comment: It can be done, not too bad apart from the typing. But the Root Test is more pleasant in this case.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Are you sure? [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%5Cfrac%7B%282*n%2B1%29%5En%29%7D%7Bn%5E%7B2*n%7D%7D&dataset=).

Comment: Fast track: For every $n\geqslant5$, $2n+1\leqslant \frac12n^2$ hence $$\frac{(2n+1)^{n}}{n^{2n}}\leqslant\frac{\left(\tfrac{1}{2}n^{2}\right)^{n}}{n^{2n}}=\frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Comment: @Did why $n \ge 5$?

Comment: Because $2n+1>\frac12n^2$ for $n=1,2,3,4$ and $2n+1\leqslant\frac12n^2$ for every $n\geqslant5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Root Test is in this case more pleasant for proving convergence. However, if Ratio Test it must be, rewrite the expression for the ratio as
$$\frac{2n+3}{(n+1)^2} \cdot \left(\frac{2n+3}{2n+1}\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{2n}.$$
The first term above has limit $0$. Let us now look at the third term. Its reciprocal is $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n}$, which has limit $e^2$.

Similarly, we can handle the slightly messier second term, which is $\left(1+\frac{2}{2n+1}\right)^n$. A little manipulation, rewriting the exponent as $(2n+1)(n/(2n+1)$, shows this has limit $e$.

So the first term has limit $0$, and the other two terms are bounded above. Thus our $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ has limit $0\lt 1$, and therefore we have convergence.

**Remark:** We could have computed less. For example the third term is clearly less than $1$, so we don't need to worry about it. And we don't need to find the exact limit of the second term, as long as we show it is bounded above.

Comment: This is exactly the approach I would recommend if one insists on using the ratio test.   I might have written $$\left(1+\frac{2}{2n+1}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1/2}\right)^{n+1/2}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n+1/2}}}$$to find that this term approaches $e$.  So, +1

Answer (score 0):

$$\left| \frac{(2n+3)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{2n+2}} \cdot \frac{n^{2n}}{(2n+1)^n} \right|<\left| \frac{(2n+3)^{n+1}}{n^{2n+2}} \cdot \frac{n^{2n}}{(2n+1)^n} \right| =\frac{(2n+3)^{n+1}}{n^2*(2n+1)^n}=\frac{1}{n^2}*\frac{(2+\frac{3}{n})^{n+1}*n}{(2+\frac{1}{n})^n}<\frac{2n}{n^2}=\frac{2}{n}$$Since $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{2}{n} \right|=0,$$ We have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|<1$$
Thus, the series converges

Comment: how $(2n+3)^{n+1} < (2n+1)^{n+1}$?

Comment: sorry, let me edit this. a sec :)